# Can Disqus be programatically made read-only / read-write?

Tags: disqus

For a new site we’d like users to have to log in to be able to leave comments but would like all users to read them. Is there a way to programmatically set Disqus into a read-only mode on a per-call basis?

For the time being we’re just wrapping the entire Disqus block in an if-logged-in statement which is acceptable, but showing the existing comments to all users would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen that you can disable guest commenting in the Disqus admin > settings page? When that's turned on, comments can be read but a login via Disqus, Google, Facebook or Twitter is required to leave a comment.

Comment: The OP did ask for a "programmatic way" but this is the best answer/solution unless the OP can provide a use case for why they would need to dynamically change the comment permissions.

Comment: The owner of the site wants to drive signups to their system and to sweeten the deal wants privileges including commenting rights extended to users who’ve done so. Unfortunately I don’t think your suggestion does what we want, but thanks for replying anyway.

Comment: @Robin This is definitely functionality we're trying to avoid (the point is to make any site available to a user with an account). However, we've implemented something called AudienceSync, which is going through closed testing right now, but you can read about it here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1013695 -- essentially it'll sync information about the user back to you. That might be a better solution than this down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ryan, interesting. I understand that my original query wouldn’t be what Disqus wants, it’s not what I would have gone for either.

Comment: @RyanV: I have a similar situation to this. My project has some similarities to Stackoverflow. Some news users spam the comment boxes with `+1`, `:)` and even post something irrelevant to the page data. So I thought of adding reputation like feature to the members. So if a person have say 20 reputation he can be unlocked for commenting. Because everyone login with their Facebook or Disqus account and start commenting something. So it would be better if you add something with server side approach.